# Injecting app level username/userid into nginx/Apache log

Tags: django, apache, logging, nginx

Is there a way to inject an application level username or id (in this case, the django username or id) into the Apache or ngnix log? Note that I'm not asking about the HTTP auth username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do something like this, only we tell Apache to store the the Django sessionid cookie.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %{sessionid}C" withsession
CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log withsession
```

It's sort of a two-step process to map the sessionid to the user, but it's easy to implement. You could do something similar by setting a cookie with the explicit ID in it and then using the custom log to capture it.

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't aware of the "C" option in logging, that'll likely work.

Answer (score 16):

I'm currently using a short custom middleware to add this data to response headers, as below:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
class RemoteUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            response['X-Remote-User-Name'] = request.user.username
            response['X-Remote-User-Id'] = request.user.id
        return response
```

With this in place, you can just use [`%{X-Remote-User-Name}o` and `%{X-Remote-User-Id}o`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) in your Apache config (or similar for nginx) and get the information straight into your logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cookie for username, say "uname", you may add %{uname}C, like this:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %{uname}C %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

Here X-Forwarded-For is user ip address. My app server is tomcat8 with Spring security. Output is like this:

```
24.xx.xx.xxx user.name - - [09/Sep/2016:19:33:21 -0400] "GET /xxxx HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://xxx/xxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```