# Django: Store user id in cookie

Tags: django, apache, session, session-cookies

I'd like to store a unique user identifier in a cookie (in order to be able to [include it in the apache log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821029/injecting-app-level-username-userid-into-nginx-apache-log)). I'm thinking of overriding the login method and setting the cookie on success.

Does that sound right? Any reason I should not do this, or is there a better way? Is there a code snippet that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

That linked answer uses the Django session cookie, which is already set automatically.

Comment: I believe the session cookie changes over time (ie. is not a consistent indicator of user id).